# how to enable Intel AES-NI support in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

How to enable AES-NI support in linux kernel. While searching on internet I found that once AES-NI enabled there should be a line "CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES_NI_INTEL=m" in kernel configuration file. I tried to recompile my kernel version 2.6.35.6 but no luck. My server hardware configuration are (Supermicro 6026T, Intel® Xeon® Processor E5640) which support AES-NI.

with kind regards
lalit